# Would this graphic card be repairable?

Tags: graphics-card, bsod, laptop-repair

Dell XPS M1710 laptop
Windows 7 Ultimate

---

From a certain moment I got a BSoD when booting, after which the PC rebooted. It was persistent, though I never have the time to read the error message properly before it rebooted. It was something like "Windows shut down to protect against damage". In any case it was not a software exception message.

Since it didn't boot any more I reinstalled Win7 and it worked again. Until I installed the driver for the video card. Then the BSoD returned. I'm sure the driver is OK. (You need the driver to work at the native resolution of 1920x1200.)

Another reinstall, this time without installing the video driver. The PC has been working nicely for a week or so now, so my conclusion is that the video card is partly broken. Partly, because at its current resolution of 1024x768 it works.

Is this something that usually can be repaired? What are the usual suspects?

**edit**
I tried Journeyman Geek's suggestion of the Linux test. I used a Knoppix CD I have lying around. During boot it switches to a high-resolution mode, at least that's what I think given the very small character size. But after booting I get a screen with a couple of vertical bands about 1/4 of the screen width: alternating light and dark, containing much fine noise ("confetti"). There's a faint cursor, but that's it. I don't manage to get anything out of it. (I'm not very much acquainted with Linux). Anyway the screen doesn't look good.

**edit 2**
When Windows crashed a minidump was created. I wanted to look at it with WinDbg, but can't seem to install the SDK, which I understand is required. So I uploaded the minidump [here](http://www.filesend.net/download.php?f=ed647b65e218ac8591b78907bd09bb5d). It would be nice if someone with a working WinDbg could at least post the error message in an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to download the driver? And are you downloading the driver from Windows Update or the official one?

Comment: I'd try it at the full resolution off a linux livecd to rule out the hardware.

Comment: @DaveRook: You need the driver to work at full resolution. I downloaded the driver from the Dell website.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: that's a great idea. I'm gonna try it right away and report back.

Comment: if it's on warranty send it back, it's certainly a hardware issue like you figured out. If it's repairable without placing a new motherboard is undeterminable by us, you'd have to let a specialist diagnose the motherboard videochip. The answer is probably "No, you need to buy a new motherboard for the laptop because most laptops don't have swappable video cards"

Comment: @Gizmo: Warranty? 'fraid not, the thing is at least 5 years old.

Comment: Yeah I thought there is no warranty nymore becjause you ask it here, but better ask to be sure xD

Comment: upload the .dmp files, so that we can see which BSOD you get.

Comment: what's the card on it? I'm looking it up and seeing a 7000 series, but if its a 8000 series nvidia, its probably one of the flawed models that keeps dying.

Comment: @magicandre, the minidump is a binary file, how can you read it?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: SiSoft Sandra says it's an nVidia GeForce Go 7900 GS. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: open it with WinDbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Answer (score 0):

The definitely sounds like bump underfill cracking. As the GPU heats and cools, the connections between the GPU and the motherboard expand and contract. Eventually, the bump underfill cracks and reliable contact is no longer made. There's always the [oven fix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zWDgYl4ns0w), if you have nothing to lose.